# What's the (still negative) opposite of "arrogant"

Tags: word-request

The answer is **not** the word *humble* nor any derivation thereof. ***Arrogant*** being negative epithet has a positive counterpart of *humble* but I'm looking for the negative opposite, instead.

***Arrogant*** conduct is assuming that ones success is the result of ones excellence and failing to consider that it might be subject to advantageous circumstances.

The opposite of that would be failing to see that any of the progress is due to ones skills nor competence. And that's a negative concept as well.

I can express it by ***overly humble*** or ***excessively timid/self-critical*** but I want a single word term for precisely that, rather than a description of the property. ***Insecure*** won't do because that's a different concept - I'm talking about someone who too often assumes that the success is due to fortunate circumstances.

Comment: It may help if you put a person with such attitude or feeling into a context. Can you make some real or imaginary example?

Comment: Does a word exist in your native language? Have you used a bilingual dictionary?

Comment: @JamesK I don't know. I'm trying to find one but failed and I was hoping that if I find it in English, I can hit the dictionary using it. The best answer suggested *self-deprecating* and I'm satisfied with it. Sadly, it's not really translateable into Swedish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term that first came to mind was  [self-deprecating](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-deprecating): *tending or serving to disparage or undervalue oneself*, but it doesn’t have a negative connotation. You could make it negative by adding “excessively” or “annoyingly”, but without an example of how you want to use the word you’re looking for, it’s difficult to say whether it fits.

Being self-deprecating if you are a celebrity or have a lot of power can be a positive quality. Self-deprecating humor (in general) can be seen as a positive thing unless it is excessive.

[Self-effacing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-effacing): *having or showing a tendency to make oneself modestly or shyly inconspicuous*, is a related word. I don’t think it fits though because it is more about avoiding attention than being self-critical.

Comment: I find *self-deprecating* suitable for the situations I imagine. It's not negative, as such, but it's kind of leans rather towards negative rather than positive charge. I can't imagine hearing *oh, wow, what a impressive and self-deprecating dude you are*. The two epithets grind against each other.

Answer (score 3):

Removing any words I would consider *positive* from this list of **antonyms** of arrogant I found on [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/arrogant):

> Near Antonyms of arrogant:
>
> > cowering, cringing, mousy (or mousey), overmodest, sheepish, shrinking, shy, subdued, timid, meek, submissive, unassertive, yielding

It's hard to pick one without knowing the context in which you are using it.